# find scroll zone on mouse hover...?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

This is my image. What I want to describe..

When I hover on this mouse hover scroll zone **top** area, then this function will be run.

```
verticalSlideDown();
```

when I hover on this mouse hover scroll zone **bottom** area, then this function will be run. But how can I measure this bottom scroll zone area and run this function?

```
verticalSlideUp();
```

This is my js code

```
 function mousePositionTop(){
var x,y;
$(".scroll-middle-container").mousemove(function(event){
    var offset = $(this).offset();
    x = event.pageX - offset.left;
    y = event.pageY - offset.top;
    $("#result").html("X : "+x+" Y : "+y);
    if (y >= 1 && y <= 150 ) {
        //verticalSlideUp();
        verticalSlideDown();
        console.log("position Y : "+y );
    } else{
        var div= $(".scroll-inner-container");

       div.stop();
    }
  });
 };  
mousePositionTop();
```

This is my text area with div height `70vh`.
This is html css code

```
<div class="scroll-inner-container">
  <div class="paragraph-space content">
    <h1>top position</h1>
      <h3 id="result"></h3>
      <p>Lorem ipsum</p>
      <h1>end position</h1>
 </div>
</div>
```

css code:

```
.scroll-inner-container{
height: -moz-calc(70vh + 0px);
height: -webkit-calc(70vh + 0px);
height: calc(70vh + 0px);
overflow: auto;
object-fit: cover;
background-color: yellow;
position: relative;
}
```

Here is my snippet

```js
    //Random Id Generator
    function makeid() {
      var text = "";
      var possible = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789";

      for (var i = 0; i < 5; i++)
        text += possible.charAt(Math.floor(Math.random() * possible.length));

      return text;
    }
    
//scroll function top
    function verticalSlideUp(){
        $(".scroll-inner-container").each(function(){
            let id = makeid();
            var div = $(this);
            div.stop();
            $(this).attr("id",id);
            var remHeight = div[0].scrollHeight - $(this).height();
            var scrollableHeight = remHeight - div.scrollTop();
            var pos = div.scrollTop();
            var remainingTime = (scrollableHeight - pos) * 100 / 5; //here 5 is a speed
            // console.log("pos : "+ pos);
            div.animate({
                scrollTop:remHeight
            },{
                duration: remainingTime,
                easing: "linear",
            });
        });
    };
    
    
    //scroll function down
    
       function verticalSlideDown(){
        $(".scroll-inner-container").each(function(){
            let id = makeid();
            var div = $(this);
            
            div.stop();
            $(this).attr("id",id);
            var remHeight = div[0].scrollHeight - $(this).height();
            var scrollableHeight = remHeight - div.scrollTop();
            var pos = div.scrollTop();
            // console.log("pos : "+ pos);
            var remainingTime = (pos * 100) / 5; //here 5 is a speed

            div.animate({
                scrollTop:0
            },{
                duration: remainingTime,
                easing: "linear",

            });

        });
    };
    
    function mousePositionTop(){
    var x,y;
    $(".scroll-middle-container").mousemove(function(event){
        var offset = $(this).offset();
        x = event.pageX - offset.left;
        y = event.pageY - offset.top;
        $("#result").html("X : "+x+" Y : "+y);
        if (y >= 1 && y <= 150 ) {
            verticalSlideUp();
            // verticalSlideDown();
            console.log("position Y : "+y );
        } else{
            var div= $(".scroll-inner-container");
            
           div.stop();
        }
    });
};
```

```css
.scroll-inner-container{
    height: -moz-calc(70vh + 0px);
    height: -webkit-calc(70vh + 0px);
    height: calc(70vh + 0px);
    overflow: auto;
    object-fit: cover;
    background-color: yellow;
    position: relative;
}
```

```html
<div class="scroll-outer-container">
       <div class="scroll-middle-container">
        <span class="mouse-scroll-top-div"></span>
        <div class="scroll-inner-container">
         <div class="paragraph-space content">
          <h1>top position</h1>
           <h3 id="result"></h3>
           <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Veritatis omnis aspernatur quam minus tempora quis quibusdam officiis fuga asperiores, quos consectetur facilis recusandae, dolore voluptatibus iure laboriosam et perferendis commodi consequatur harum ullam ex praesentium. Officia facere unde animi dolore quisquam cum, expedita! Optio odio repudiandae quas saepe pariatur, necessitatibus aspernatur magni. Quasi aut enim explicabo ipsum provident eum molestias ut velit soluta nam, quam, cumque possimus natus sunt ipsam? Harum sunt nobis modi deleniti esse, dolorum laudantium earum obcaecati, a eos veniam odio, architecto illo debitis consequuntur iure eius quidem voluptatem possimus libero omnis, in laborum. Quisquam hic atque odit error suscipit beatae dolore eos molestiae alias repudiandae provident excepturi expedita, adipisci architecto, quia ex dolorem ab deleniti qui sapiente? Voluptate sed nam maiores eaque fugiat quibusdam laudantium optio quidem molestias commodi autem sunt obcaecati dignissimos tempora consequatur sit natus ad delectus voluptatibus, est, quis, praesentium dicta! Cupiditate ullam dolor laudantium esse nobis provident adipisci perferendis, minus dolore iure aliquam vero unde fuga magni id similique excepturi ea accusantium. Quos ea blanditiis iste repudiandae aspernatur aut quidem accusantium itaque consequuntur odit voluptas corporis in harum quo, voluptatibus exercitationem dolores, eveniet dignissimos voluptatem ducimus fugiat magni ullam. Ducimus magni optio consequuntur mollitia commodi ratione autem aspernatur expedita corrupti, voluptates ab numquam incidunt saepe eum sint distinctio provident cumque ullam, eveniet omnis, blanditiis assumenda dolorum. Dolorum, rem ducimus in tempore quae pariatur enim ut officia et minus labore soluta repellat nesciunt, velit iusto cupiditate! Quas nisi nostrum harum assumenda porro, corporis natus quod. Facilis repellat obcaecati pariatur corrupti, animi non. Neque nisi vero corporis quo tempora, voluptatum illum voluptates porro ipsum. Accusamus debitis doloribus nesciunt laudantium nobis explicabo ullam illo dicta adipisci, mollitia iure delectus aut nihil autem tempora laboriosam eum perspiciatis ipsa totam qui porro. Accusantium sequi molestiae, sint fugiat esse. Blanditiis sunt aliquam hic modi sit, quae fugit laboriosam culpa cum tenetur ea debitis officia dolorem sequi excepturi voluptatum velit adipisci, dolore sapiente, quaerat cumque nemo. Soluta eum molestias consequatur eligendi, quibusdam repellat dolorem, tempore aliquid commodi nisi provident excepturi debitis laudantium? Minus dolorum unde atque eum optio obcaecati ipsa necessitatibus laborum possimus commodi ea voluptas temporibus ut alias eligendi quas, nobis dolor, praesentium totam? Perspiciatis ad similique delectus earum totam iure incidunt! Debitis soluta fuga, veniam non vero neque rerum libero nesciunt minus. Voluptatum, natus, doloremque! Accusantium at doloribus, ipsum nostrum amet fugit quaerat in fugiat expedita excepturi, tenetur voluptatem totam autem dicta accusamus illum. Consequatur eos libero, odit, modi sit temporibus voluptates quae error magnam doloremque aliquid beatae facere! Earum expedita illum repudiandae minus nesciunt eum reiciendis sit nulla blanditiis temporibus qui laudantium, accusantium tempora quos similique? Repellat eaque accusantium blanditiis ab earum suscipit inventore commodi explicabo fugiat aliquam placeat, soluta rerum iste consectetur, minus debitis molestias dolorum harum obcaecati veritatis nihil quibusdam ipsam. Repellat sequi, tempora sed quae ipsum. Autem enim odio accusamus sequi, labore minus at corrupti aut earum alias itaque corporis vel perspiciatis laudantium rerum temporibus quaerat necessitatibus, iusto molestiae! Similique itaque a, fugiat!</p>

          <h1>end position</h1>
         </div>
        </div>
        
       </div>

      </div>
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your issue is because you have put your `mousemove` event inside a function and you never call this. I execute your event directly on load page. Please try

```js
//Random Id Generator
    function makeid() {
      var text = "";
      var possible = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789";

      for (var i = 0; i < 5; i++)
        text += possible.charAt(Math.floor(Math.random() * possible.length));

      return text;
    }
    
//scroll function top
    function verticalSlideUp(){
        $(".scroll-inner-container").each(function(){
            let id = makeid();
            var div = $(this);
            div.stop();
            $(this).attr("id",id);
            var remHeight = div[0].scrollHeight - $(this).height();
           
            var scrollableHeight = remHeight - div.scrollTop();
            var pos = div.scrollTop();
            var remainingTime = (remHeight - pos) * 100 / 5; 

            div.animate({
                scrollTop:remHeight
            },{
                duration: remainingTime,
                easing: "linear",
            });
        });
    };
    
    
    //scroll function down
    
       function verticalSlideDown(){
        $(".scroll-inner-container").each(function(){
            let id = makeid();
            var div = $(this);
            
            div.stop();
            $(this).attr("id",id);
            var remHeight = div[0].scrollHeight - $(this).height();
            var scrollableHeight = remHeight - div.scrollTop();
            var pos = div.scrollTop();
            // console.log("pos : "+ pos);
            var remainingTime = (pos * 100) / 5; //here 5 is a speed

            div.animate({
                scrollTop:0
            },{
                duration: remainingTime,
                easing: "linear",

            });

        });
    };

var x,y;
$(".scroll-middle-container").mousemove(function(event){
    var offset = $(this).offset();
    x = event.pageX - offset.left;
    y = event.pageY - offset.top;
    $("#result").html("X : "+x+" Y : "+y);
    var div= $(".scroll-inner-container");
    if (y >= 1 && y <= 50 ) {
        verticalSlideDown();
    }else if (y >= ($(this).outerHeight() - 50) ) {
        verticalSlideUp();
    }else{
        div.stop()
    }
});
```

```css
.scroll-inner-container{
    height: -moz-calc(70vh + 0px);
    height: -webkit-calc(70vh + 0px);
    height: calc(70vh + 0px);
    overflow: auto;
    object-fit: cover;
    background-color: yellow;
    position: relative;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="scroll-outer-container">
 <div class="scroll-middle-container">
  <span class="mouse-scroll-top-div"></span>
  <div class="scroll-inner-container">
   <div class="paragraph-space content">
    <h1>top position</h1>
     <h3 id="result"></h3>
     <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Veritatis omnis aspernatur quam minus tempora quis quibusdam officiis fuga asperiores, quos consectetur facilis recusandae, dolore voluptatibus iure laboriosam et perferendis commodi consequatur harum ullam ex praesentium. Officia facere unde animi dolore quisquam cum, expedita! Optio odio repudiandae quas saepe pariatur, necessitatibus aspernatur magni. Quasi aut enim explicabo ipsum provident eum molestias ut velit soluta nam, quam, cumque possimus natus sunt ipsam? Harum sunt nobis modi deleniti esse, dolorum laudantium earum obcaecati, a eos veniam odio, architecto illo debitis consequuntur iure eius quidem voluptatem possimus libero omnis, in laborum. Quisquam hic atque odit error suscipit beatae dolore eos molestiae alias repudiandae provident excepturi expedita, adipisci architecto, quia ex dolorem ab deleniti qui sapiente? Voluptate sed nam maiores eaque fugiat quibusdam laudantium optio quidem molestias commodi autem sunt obcaecati dignissimos tempora consequatur sit natus ad delectus voluptatibus, est, quis, praesentium dicta! Cupiditate ullam dolor laudantium esse nobis provident adipisci perferendis, minus dolore iure aliquam vero unde fuga magni id similique excepturi ea accusantium. Quos ea blanditiis iste repudiandae aspernatur aut quidem accusantium itaque consequuntur odit voluptas corporis in harum quo, voluptatibus exercitationem dolores, eveniet dignissimos voluptatem ducimus fugiat magni ullam. Ducimus magni optio consequuntur mollitia commodi ratione autem aspernatur expedita corrupti, voluptates ab numquam incidunt saepe eum sint distinctio provident cumque ullam, eveniet omnis, blanditiis assumenda dolorum. Dolorum, rem ducimus in tempore quae pariatur enim ut officia et minus labore soluta repellat nesciunt, velit iusto cupiditate! Quas nisi nostrum harum assumenda porro, corporis natus quod. Facilis repellat obcaecati pariatur corrupti, animi non. Neque nisi vero corporis quo tempora, voluptatum illum voluptates porro ipsum. Accusamus debitis doloribus nesciunt laudantium nobis explicabo ullam illo dicta adipisci, mollitia iure delectus aut nihil autem tempora laboriosam eum perspiciatis ipsa totam qui porro. Accusantium sequi molestiae, sint fugiat esse. Blanditiis sunt aliquam hic modi sit, quae fugit laboriosam culpa cum tenetur ea debitis officia dolorem sequi excepturi voluptatum velit adipisci, dolore sapiente, quaerat cumque nemo. Soluta eum molestias consequatur eligendi, quibusdam repellat dolorem, tempore aliquid commodi nisi provident excepturi debitis laudantium? Minus dolorum unde atque eum optio obcaecati ipsa necessitatibus laborum possimus commodi ea voluptas temporibus ut alias eligendi quas, nobis dolor, praesentium totam? Perspiciatis ad similique delectus earum totam iure incidunt! Debitis soluta fuga, veniam non vero neque rerum libero nesciunt minus. Voluptatum, natus, doloremque! Accusantium at doloribus, ipsum nostrum amet fugit quaerat in fugiat expedita excepturi, tenetur voluptatem totam autem dicta accusamus illum. Consequatur eos libero, odit, modi sit temporibus voluptates quae error magnam doloremque aliquid beatae facere! Earum expedita illum repudiandae minus nesciunt eum reiciendis sit nulla blanditiis temporibus qui laudantium, accusantium tempora quos similique? Repellat eaque accusantium blanditiis ab earum suscipit inventore commodi explicabo fugiat aliquam placeat, soluta rerum iste consectetur, minus debitis molestias dolorum harum obcaecati veritatis nihil quibusdam ipsam. Repellat sequi, tempora sed quae ipsum. Autem enim odio accusamus sequi, labore minus at corrupti aut earum alias itaque corporis vel perspiciatis laudantium rerum temporibus quaerat necessitatibus, iusto molestiae! Similique itaque a, fugiat!</p>
    <h1>end position</h1>
   </div>
  </div> 
 </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you. @p.Frank .but also when i hover in bottom area within 150px (bottom to 150px) then scroll will be  down.this is scroll down function `verticalSlideDown()`

Comment: Ok try the update snippet. I have remove the `div.stop();` and add your two function event. You can make an intermediate step for no move between two height. Please try

Comment: is it what you want? @Masud001

Comment: Thank you man..! @P.Frank....it's almost same .But there have 2 function.and  hoverable zone.it's 150px from top and 150px from bottom.when i hover from bottom to 150px. then `verticalSlideDown()` function will be start. otherwise it will be stop..you can see the mage, i have shared.

Comment: you can see this link [link here](http://unix.dbrqx.com:60081/index1/pf_simple.html)

Comment: Ok try now. i have put the size to 50px scroll Zone and add a step for stop scrolling

Comment: Now is exactly what you want :-)

Comment: Thank you man !!! it's works.Thank you.all is fine but only problem is..please see that video when you have time...i really appreciate that..!!!
[video link](http://brqxportals.com/unix_page_sudden_10_2017.mp4)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/156091/discussion-between-masud001-and-p-frank).

Comment: @Masud001 Yes now is work fine. it is because you used `scrollableHeight` for speed calculation while `remHeight ` in verticalSlideUp function